# Big difference between Google Analytics and Piwik

Tags: google-analytics, matomo

I have notice my Piwik visitors drop recently so I looked on Analytics which is my backup statistics and noticed that it is counting a lot more visitors than Piwik.

Yesterday Piwik registered 5 visitors, compared to Google registering 20.

I'm quite sure I haven't had this difference before. Can anyone suggest what is causing this problem?

Comment: Google is not as good at determining bot verses human as others simply because they are using a bug that is limited in scope. Google is good, but not as good as others. It may be that Piwik is more accurately measuring real humans where as Google cannot and is mistaking some bot activity as humans. How does your total accesses including bots add up between the two?? Or is your example the total??

Comment: @closetnoc That is the total in the example. I have turned off bot counting on Google for now but could it really be causing a 75% of my website traffic (on Google)?

Comment: Let's see, 68,000 page requests from bots and 250 from real humans in one day is normal here.

Comment: Bots that fetch the JavaScript for Analytics though?  Almost no bots do that.

Comment: I hate to say it, but a lot of bots are found in my Google Analytics. I can match GA traffic with log file and other data I have and know that some bots do use JS. Bummer!! Obviously search engines do but you would expect Google to know this. But sadly, I have found others.